# Get data from sql database in chartjs using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, chart.js, codeigniter-3

I have a function in controller to get data from sql database. Problem is that I am not getting json data in chart, Can anybody please explain, Why? BIG Thanks

I have included all the required cdn for CI and AJAX and Chart
Here is the controller.

```
    public function get_chart_data(){
    $survey_id = $this->session->userdata('get_survey_id');
    $count_yes = $this->global_model->select_single('survey_replies',
                       ['survey_id'=>$survey_id,'reply_message'=>'1']);
    echo json_encode($count_yes);
}
```

Here I want to print that chart

```
 <canvas id="myChart" max-width="300" max-height="300"></canvas>
```

And in the script tags

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  url:'<?php echo site_url("user/get_chart_data"); ?>',
  success:function(response)
  {
    var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      data.push(response[i].reply_message);

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: {
              labels: ["Yes", "No"],
              datasets: [{
                  label: '# of Votes',
                  data: data,
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
       
                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                      'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  ],
                  borderWidth: 2
              }]
          },

      });
      
    }
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Compare structures of what `myChart.data.dataSets[0].data` expected to be and `json_encode($count_yes)`.

Comment: You should set a dataType for your ajax. jQuery says it will try to intelligently guess the dataType if not provided, but in my experience it does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping unnecessary myChart.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  url:'<?php echo site_url("user/get_chart_data"); ?>',
  success:function(response)
  {
    var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      data.push(response[i].reply_message);
     }


      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: {
              labels: ["Yes", "No"],
              datasets: [{
                  label: '# of Votes',
                  data: data,
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',

                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                      'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  ],
                  borderWidth: 2
              }]
          },

      });


  }
});

});
```